# Change sitemap URL in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Normally sitemap urls are rewritten to sitemap.xml, sitemap_index.xml
Can I rewrite sitemap URL, I want to hide my sitemap URL

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to save the permalinks settings from WordPress dashboard again...
and then create a sitemap of the website.